# Changing background image on hover in <a> tag

Tags: html, css, hover

I need to put an image link on my webpage, when they hover over the image I want it to change to another image. I am having trouble doing this.

I this line in my html:

```
<a href="mailto:ellie@example.com?subject=test" id="somethingtosay-ballon" class="item"> hello</a>
```

my css classes are:

```
#somethingtosay-ballon
{   
    background-image: url(Images/button_email_upstate.png); 
    display:block;

    width:263px;
    height:167px;
    text-indent:-9999px; 
    position:absolute;
    top:643px;
    left:530px;


}
#somethingtosay-ballon .item:hover
{   
    background-image: url(Images/button_email_mouseover.png); 
    display:block;

    width:263px;
    height:167px;
    text-indent:-9999px; 
    position:absolute;
    top:643px;
    left:530px;

}
```

Can Anyone tell me the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between `#somethingtosay-ballon` and `.item:hover`. It should be:

```
#somethingtosay-ballon.item:hover
```

Comment: `#somethingtosay-ballon` is already of class `.item`. Isn't that redundant?

Comment: By way of explanation, `#id.class` matches elements with both the id and class; `#id .class` matches sub-elements of `#id` with class `.class`.

Comment: @Dutchie `#somethingtosay-ballon" has the `item` class, but this answer isn't "adding" the class, it's only using it as a selector. Your use of "already" doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Not true `#somethingtosay-ballon:hover` is the same as `#somethingtosay-ballon.item:hover` since the object has that id as class as well.

Comment: Yes, that's the same. Since you're using an ID to select this node there should only be one match and therefor the `item` class is unnecessary in this selector.

Comment: @Karl It could be that he wants to toggle some visual effect by adding/removing the class `.item`. It is not incorrect to select both by id and class, and sometimes it is important.

Answer (score 2):

The entire second selector should be

```
#somethingtosay-ballon:hover
{   
    background-image: url(Images/button_email_mouseover.png); 
}
```

You do not need to repeat all of the duplicated rules, and you do not need to include `.item` in the selector. You can add the `:hover` pseduoclass directly to the `#id` selector.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the background of `somethingtosay-ballon`, try

`#somethingtosay-ballon:hover`